# android webview history does not work properly

Tags: android, webview

My application loads a url of a website into an android webview.
This website consists of 3 pages (actually its the same page with different ID)
lets call them A B & C.
The website, has a back button, which code is:

```
javascript:history.go(-1)
```

If i browse from A to B and presses the back button - it works fine.

If I browse from B to C and presses the back button - I get back to B - also fine.

If I then press the back button, I get back to C instead of getting to A - NOT fine.
Then If i press back I will get back to B...back again to C...and then to B...endlessly, I never get to A.

If I use the physical back of the device and use the following, it works as expected:

```
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
```

Extra info:
I am using a WebViewClient, override "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" and enable javascript:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: @hogni89 - I did resolve this issue. What caused the problem was "shouldOverrideUrlLoading"  - I Needed to handle specific URL's there. The problem was I was returning "true". If You want the internal browser to handle the history, You should return false, though it depends on what You need to preform inside "shouldOverrideUrlLoading".
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I write code like this

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
                return true;
            }
            if (mOnWebViewEventListener != null) {
                mOnWebViewEventListener.onWebViewPageStart(view);
            }

            if (mShowProgress) {
                mProgressBar.show();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

It's work or not?